# Exception mapping on Client side

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

I'm trying to force resteasy client to throw my own/custom business exceptions mapped from status code and entity in response.

I know how to map exceptions for my own status codes with server-side [exception mappers](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#ExceptionMappers), but I don't know how to "unmap" them automatically (with some "unmapping" logic of course) on client side to get the proper exceptions...

I know that exception mapping on client side is done in [ClientInvocation#handleErrorStatus](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/internal/ClientInvocation.html#handleErrorStatus(javax.ws.rs.core.Response)).

The question is how can I overwrite this default behavior?!

Answer (score 4):

You can intercept the ClientInvocation with a [ClientResponseFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientResponseFilter.html):

```
@Provider
public class ClientErrorFilter implements ClientResponseFilter {

   @Override
   public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext, ClientResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
       if (responseContext.getStatus() == 404) {
           throw new CustomNotFoundException();
       }
   }

}
```

The downside is that your Exception will be wrapped in a `ResponseProcessingException`:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(ClientErrorFilter.class);
try {
    client.target("http://stackoverflow.com/something-not-found").request().get();
} catch (ResponseProcessingException ex) {
    CustomNotFoundException nfex = (CustomNotFoundException) ex.getCause();
}
```